# Services to implement data synchronization in my software

Tags: c#, c++, windows, synchronization

I'm currently developing a Windows software and am looking for a way to enable data synchronization between several copies of the program.

Let me explain on a simple example: Say, the software in question lets one user count cash in their cash register. Say, another user under the same account uses another copy of the software on another cash register terminal. What I'm looking to implement is a way to take any changes that were made on one copy of the software and "push" them to any other running copies for the same signed up users, or a group of users (i.e. "sync" the data between them.)

PS. I can obviously do so using my own web server (if I set up one), but that is not the approach that I'm looking for. I was thinking about a service, much like Dropbox, that would let users of my software to sign up for a free account with them and then use it for the data synchronization in my software.

So do you have any suggestions on how to implement this (from a developers standpoint)?

Comment: have you looked at the data sync framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887625 it's not a finished service but may get you started in the right direction.

Comment: No. Thanks for the link. So is it something that MS is intending to roll out soon?

Comment: it's a framework that's been around for a while, so not new. The SQL Azure Data Sync functionality, which is overkill for your purposes, is an example of a finished service that leverages it. There may be implementation on top of it that might be closer to what you want - perhaps check codeplex.com

Answer (score -1):

Create your own database? That way, each change that one user makes is going to be visible to everybody. You could, of course, give different administrative privileges to different users to restrict the changes that they could make.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter where you create the database. All you need to do is create a link between the database and your application. If you are using Visual Studio, this option is already built-in and you simply have to follow the wizard to establish the connection. Keep in mind that Visual Studio supports SQL databases only. If you have a SAP database, you will have to create a wrapper program around the database.